# Add Two Way Menu In WordPress For Login And Logout

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking to add tow menus in wordpress theme using hooks. One menu should show on when members logged in my system and second menu will show when members are logout from system.

I am using below code but it's showing only for logged out users.

`function custom_new_menu() {
  register_nav_menus(array('custom-menu' => __( 'Custom Menu' ),'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu')));
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_new_menu' );`

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `is_user_logged_in()` function to check if the current user is logged into Wordpress.

```
function custom_new_menu() {
  if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    register_nav_menu(
      // Loads the additional nav for logged in users
      'extra-menu'  => __( 'Extra Menu')
    );
  } else {
    register_nav_menu(
      // Loads the default nav for visitors
      'custom-menu' => __( 'Custom Menu' ),
    );
  }
} 

add_action( 'init', 'custom_new_menu' );
```

- Note that the code above switched from the `register_nav_menus()` which registers multiple menus to `register_nav_menu()` which registers a single menu. The syntax for these is slightly different as we no longer need the inner array.